# How to encode a number array into a single value without Strings?

Tags: java, algorithm, indexing, encoding, decoding

I was wondering how to perform this action in a efficient way, once I need use this to map puzzle states, and this work usually uses milions of iterations etc.

Through internet I basically found approaches using String, and this is so bad for my proporses. I got to build a method to parse a array of numbers to a single `int` value (I tried to look to its hexadecimals), however I didn't found a way to build the reverse operation. This was my try:

```
    public static int stateToidx(byte[] stateArr){
        //i'm look to a fixed array size (sz=12)
        int index = stateArr[0];

        /*
        Here I just tried concatenate all elements 2 by 2 and
        increment the resulting value to a "index" field.

        Examples
        Values: [0x1,0x2,0x3,0x4...0xB,0xC]
        result = "0x12"+"0x34"+...+"0xBC"
        */
        for (int i = 0; i < stateArr.length - 1; i += 2) {
            index += (stateArr[i] << 0x4) | stateArr[i+1];
        }

        return index;
    }
```

I don't know if is possible retrieve all elements of the array in the same order only using a result number using this method (the decoding operation). Maybe the way to it is use multiplication, once we can "easly" find "products" of a number, or something like that (sorry, I'm just thinking random possibilitties). However, multiplication appears returns numbers higher than I can manipulate in the tables (arrays).

Thinking this result will be used to index other values in a array what do you suggest to build this operations? The two ways, the array encoding into a single number and the number decoding into a array.

Comment: A Java `int` is 32-bits. Your 12 byte array contains 96-bits. That could be encoded to 3 `int`(s) without any loss, but not one. Pleas explain your operation; because it is not at all clear.

Comment: Even if the values in `stateArr` are 4 bits each as the example suggests, that's still 48 bits and it still doesn't fit in an `int`

Comment: Here's one way to think of this mathematically: If you want to store *n* numbers, and each of these numbers is in the range 0 to *m* - 1 (or from 1 to *m*), there are *m* raised to the *n* power different possible distinct combinations of numbers. If *m* ^ *n* > 2 ^ 32, you're out of luck.

Comment: Guys, I'm trying to think in a counter as well, e.g., increment a counter depending of the numbers, something like if current is higher than next we increment the counter or not. I'm saying this because I'm trying to use this operations to say: "the index (encoded value) of this array carry the depth of this puzzle state (once state is the result of decoded index)". This sounds so general at this point, but will keep useful after I perform any king of pruning im my algorithm. What do you think about?

Comment: There are 2 ways I know of: 1. compression but that still needs that data density is not bigger than target storage capacity and or exploiting some property of your data  2. Randomized generations with Seed. This one can store "any" number of elements into single `int seed` but finding `seed` that will generate target array is a big problem ...  You are also limited by used PRNG so I see this also as a no GO (this one is better to generate pseudo random tables than store specific one)